# Can I get sent a copy of the deleted "What is your favourite Windbg tip/trick?" question? It has really useful information in it

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Stack Overflow makes many attempts to provide content in a stable way, e.g. we should include the relevant parts of linked websites or it has a partnership for embedded images.

I am somehow relying on that availability infrastructure, however, I'm not using the Favorites feature of Stack Overflow that often. Instead, I save links on my hard disk, so I can organize and search them.

Now I wanted to access the question [What is your favourite WinDbg tip & trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127564/what-is-your-favourite-windbg-tip-trick), which has been deleted. From the title it is quite clear that it is probably opinion-based, so I can understand the reasons for the deletion.

I don't have enough reputation to access the question and its answers and it might take more than a year until I can access it. So if someone could send me a copy, that would be nice.

What is the best practice? Should I make a backup of my favorite Stack Overflow questions and answers? I could do so, whenever I find a question is really relevant for me. However, I'd also like to benefit from new answers, so I would need a way to update my backup as long as the question has not been locked or deleted. Did anyone of you already write some sort of script to achieve that?

Comment: did you consider using [Wayback Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine)?

Comment: @gnat: Indeed, it exists - without images, but good enough: [What is your favourite WinDbg tip & trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625183254/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127564/what-is-your-favourite-windbg-tip-trick). Thanks for that. Good idea I let a copy be created by that service.

Comment: For your last paragraph, you can use the API: http://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for keeping a local bookmark to the question, noticing it went missing, and asking about it. Sad that this information was gone, but at least its back now.

Comment: If something is deleted why do we even bother hiding it from low rep users - i dont get it?

Comment: @gnat http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/ - unofficial SO deleted question archive

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Some individuals on Stack Overflow have a quest for purity; sometimes that quest gets in the way of keeping really useful information.  This is one of those cases.

WinDbg is notoriously hard to become proficient in; if you've ever used it and not come away balled up in a corner crying, you're better than me.

I've undeleted it, mostly because it does have really useful information. If we delete really useful information, we're not making the internet a better place.

Comment: Yay! If things are useful, don't delete.

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to lock, in case someone had another answer to add...

Comment: @Bruno It's a wiki answer lock. I don't want new answers, I want one canonical answer.  One of the major issues with leaving questions like this open is that they're too open ended and you end up getting pages and pages of answers that aren't useful because they take a user a long time to scroll through. With a wiki answer, simply edit the answer to include your tip.

Comment: Editing someone else's answer isn't really what SO is designed for in reality (we've had this discussion about the difference between author and editor before). SO isn't Wikipedia (and CW doesn't really work). More specifically here, each answer stands well on its own, there's no reason to edit any one of them specifically if someone wanted to add a new approach.

Comment: @Bruno We created this wiki answer lock specifically to deal with questions like these. It may hurt a sense of purity some people have, but it's a better middle ground than other approaches (leaving the question open, or nuking it from orbit).

Comment: @Bruno see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/165773

Comment: So would it make sense to edit the top-rated answer to include all the others, then flag them for deletion?

Comment: +1 for the first line.  Please keep applying that philosophy liberally.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam That would be awesome, especially if the formatting were improved to make each tip delineated from the others.

Comment: This entire scenario is a prime example of the Stack Exchange philosophy working. Community keeps itself clean, moderators handle exceptions, the appropriate flags/locks are placed on the content to keep it from getting out of control. Useful hard to find information is again in the public's hands. It's a real success story *gently wipes tear*.

Comment: @gnat Not sure this experiment really works. CW has always been rather awkward, even for single answers, it seems even worse when you get a number of distinct answers (and the possibility they may need to be merged somehow). Perhaps a better way would be not to lock such questions, but have a simple banner that says something like "This is now considered off-topic, but we're keeping this question open because it's old and provides valuable information to the community."

Comment: @Bruno Make that a feature request/discussion; let's see what the community thinks of it.

Comment: @Bruno: there is a similar banner on Skeptics.SE, for instance  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution

Comment: @nico, yes, it's locked like other locked questions on SO. What I'm suggesting is to have such a banner, but leaving the question open for new answers.

Comment: @Bruno: sure, I was mostly thinking about the wording.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: actually, what's the difference between one long answer with all the tips and lots of short(er) answers with one tip each? I guess the single answer allows for more curation/organisation, but if there isn't already repetition does it really help much?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam after around 10 answers, people start to duplicate answers, and no one ever reads to the second page. A single answer ensures focused editing and improvement, instead of scattershot.

Comment: For the future, what criteria can be used to determine whether a question seeking opinionated answers is "useful", and shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: "Post Made Community Wiki by being edited by more than 5 different editors"...I thought that all auto-wiki triggers were removed?

Comment: @santaclaus  there are several criteria that have to be taken together: votes, views, google juice, quality of information, quality of subject matter, availability of this information on the Internet.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Considering there *aren't* even five editors on that post, [you can bet that's wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237200/if-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-is-gone-why-do-the-confusing-messages-st). ;)

Comment: Wait, you can actually type *commands* into WinDBG? (... I'm joking. Kind of.)

Comment: Tell us purists what you want and stick to it.

Comment: What I want is for the purists to go get their deletion kicks on Wikipedia and stop messing up SO.